# How to Install PowerShell module programmatically?

Tags: c#, powershell

I need to install the **ExchangeOnlineManagement** module using the C# code
I used the below code to install but not working

```
    InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
    using var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
    rs.Open();
    using var ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.Runspace = rs;

     ps.AddCommand("Install-Module")
    .AddParameter("–Name", "ExchangeOnlineManagement")
    .AddParameter("-Force", true)
    .AddParameter("-AllowClobber", true).Invoke();
```

Thanks

Comment: What does this mean `but not working`?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer It throws the below error, but I installed the latest NuGet

"NuGet provider is required to interact with NuGet-based repositories. Please ensure that '2.8.5.201' or newer version of NuGet provider is installed."